# Markov property for Brownian motion; meaning of $P[B_t\in A|\mathscr{F}_S^B](\omega)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

I am reading [these notes](https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/IntroStoAn1516/IntroStochAnalysis2015.pdf) on Brownian motion. On page 22 it shows that:

$$P[B_t\in A|\mathscr{F}_S^B](\omega)=\int_A (2\pi(t-s))^{-d/2}\exp\left(-\frac{|y-B_s(\omega)|^2}{2(t-s)}\right)dy\quad \text{P-almost surley}$$
for a Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ in $\Bbb{R}^d$ over $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ with $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}^d$. I am confused here about the meaning of: $P[B_t\in A|\mathscr{F}_S^B](\omega)$. I see two problems with it:

1. $B_t$ is a random variable and as such cannot be in $A$ or for that matter $\Bbb{R}^d$ unless its argument $B$ is explicit.
2. The action of $P$ must be on elements of $\mathscr{F}$ (this is how it is defined). In this case it is not (even if $B_t$ where taken as the random variables).

My question is therefore what does  $P[B_t\in A|\mathscr{F}_S^B](\omega)$ mean? and in what space does everything live?

Comment: Please grab a decent presentation of conditional expectation in the measure theoretical sense of the term and study it.

Comment: @Did I have been using this http://www.sta.cuhk.edu.hk/cyyau/course/2013F_RMSC4005/Chapter3.pdf. My problem is not that I don't understand the notation i.e. I know what a probability given a sigma-algebra means. But my problem here is that things appear to be in the wrong spaces.

Comment: i.e. $B_t$ is a random variable from $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ to $(\Bbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R}))$ and is not itself in $\Bbb{R}^d$ as the above would seem to be implying.

Comment: Indeed, $B_t$ is in $\mathbb R^d$ almost surely, $C=[B_t\in A]$ is in $\mathcal F$ for every Borel subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^d$ and, for every sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal G$ of $\mathcal F$, $P(C\mid\mathcal G)$ is a real valued random variable defined on $\Omega$ ($P$-uniquely, up to null sets). What does not fit, in your view?

Comment: Pretty sure that lowercase $s$ and capital $S$ should be the same thing here.

Comment: @Did sorry please can you explain why $B_t \in \Bbb{R}^d$ a.s.. From what I have read since posting this question the notation $B_t\in A$ actually means the set $\{\omega|B_t(\omega)\in A\}$ which is not what you seem to be indicating.

Comment: **This is exactly what I am "indicating"**, pleas explain what makes you think otherwise. Here is a true statement which might help your understanding (or not, since at present you are most unclear about what confuses you): $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid B_t(\omega)\in\mathbb R^d\}=\Omega$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable, and $A\subset\mathbb R$ is a Borel set, then $[X\in A]$ is shorthand for the event $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A\}$. This is extremely widely used, making it quite surprising that you have studied both Brownian motion and conditional expectation without encountering it.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. I am dyslexic and as such the way I self teach myself is probably very different to other people - I do it by asking myself questions and when those questions arn't easily searchable in book indexes or online I have real problems (hence why I often resort to SE). Since I don't (and can't) read textbooks in the order they are written I often miss things like this :).

Comment: Oh, how interesting. How helpful is intuition to you? Before even meeting measure theory, most would think of a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ as just a real number which is 'random' (obviously we need the measure theory to make rigorous what we mean by this). Then $P[X\in A]$ reads "the probability that this random number $X$ lies in the set $A$", rather than some measure theoretic statement about a measurable set. Does that make sense? Do you see how the two correspond to one another?